# How to implement a class function for incrementing counter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, datadog

How would I use the following to create a *function* or *class* so that I can import this module to increment a count anytime an event has happen in my app.

I don't want to input those 3 lines everywhere on my app whenever i need to increment a count.

```
const metrics = request.server.app.metrics;
const metricName = 'user.additem.counter';
metrics.counter(metricName).inc();
```

This is what i have so far but it's not working.

```
const hoek = require('hoek')
 const incrementCounter = (context, metricName) => {
    const appMetrics = hoek.reach(context, 'request.server.app.metrics');
    if (appMetrics) {
        appMetrics.counter(metricName).inc();
    }
 };

module.exports = { 
    incrementCounter
};
```

Comment: Doesn't look too bad. Do you get an error or what isn't working? How do you call your module?

Comment: the _context_ parameter is not working for some reason. I have imported the the file and when i tried incrementCounter(_event_, _testName_)

Comment: but it will work if i tried
`const metrics = request.server.app.metrics;
 const metricName = '_testName_';
metrics.counter(metricName).inc();`

Answer (score 0):

So now you just import the function whenever you want to use it. (given that you're function works).

Assuming you saved the function as `incrementCounterFile.js`, You just include the file wherever you want to use it. If you're using require then

```
const incrementCounter = require('incrementCounterFile').incrementCounter;
incrementCounter(..)
```

Or you can use ES6 `import` also

```
import { incrementCounter } from './incrementCounterFile'
incrementCounter(..)
```

Hope I understood your question.

Comment: i have imported and used the required, but it seems the function is not working.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. When you used `require`, shouldn't you be doing `incrementCounterFile.incrementCounter(. .)`?